# List which takes type from method argument

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create method that in argument will take Type an use it as type of generic list
for example:

```
MyClass something = new MyClass();
Type myType = something.GetType();

public void createList(Type type)
{
List<type> myList = new List<type>();   // <-- How can I achieve that?
...
}
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What are you actually doing with this list after creating it? I notice your method doesn't actually return it (or anything) so I'm just wondering if there might be something better you can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by making your core method generic, like this:

```
public void createList<T>()
{
    List<T> myList = new List<T>();
    ...
}
```

And provide a non-generic overload which uses reflection to dynamically invoke the generic method:

```
public void createList(Type t)
{
    this.GetType()
        .GetMethod("createList", Type.EmptyTypes)
        .MakeGenericMethod(t)
        .Invoke(this, null);
}
```